# What is wrong in this PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to merge data into a `MySQL` table from `PHP` :

```
<?php
function convertFromDateHM($str)
{
    $tmp=$str;
    $Y=substr($tmp, 6,4); 
    $M=substr($tmp, 3,2); 
    $D=substr($tmp, 0,2);
    $H=substr($tmp, 13,2);
    $MN=substr($tmp, 18,2);
    $tmp=$Y.'-'.$M.'-'.$D.' '.$H.':'.$MN.':00';
    return $tmp;
}
function mergeCompteRendu($compterendu)
    {
        $resultat=explode("\n",$compterendu);
        $connec = mysql_connect("192.168.1.123:3306","root", "mysqlroot");
        mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connec);
        mysql_select_db("finance",$connec);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($resultat) ; $i++)
        {
            $valeur=explode(";",$resultat[$i]);
            if ($valeur[0] != '0')  // case of update
            {
                $requete = mysql_query("UPDATE compte_rendu SET  
                cr_date    = '".convertFromDateHM($valeur[1])."',
                cr_lieu    = '".$valeur[2]."',
                cred_id    = '".$valeur[3]."',
                cr_resultat = '".$valeur[5]."',
                cr_comment = '".$valeur[6]."',
                adc_id = '".$valeur[7]."' 
                WHERE cr_id = '".$valeur[0]."'");  // cr_id is the primary key which is auto_increment
            }
            else   // case of insert : here is the problem raised
            {
                $requete = mysql_query("INSERT INTO compte_rendu(cr_date,cr_lieu,cred_id,cr_resultat,cr_comment,adc_id) SET 
                                        cr_date    = '".convertFromDateHM($valeur[1])."',
                                        cr_lieu    = '".$valeur[2]."',
                                        cred_id    = '".$valeur[3]."',
                                        cr_resultat = '".$valeur[5]."',
                                        cr_comment = '".$valeur[6]."',
                                        adc_id = '".$valeur[7]."' ");
            }
        }
        return $resultat[0];
    }
```

**NB** : the "**cr_date**" column is of `datatype` `datetime`.

This `PHP` is a `webservice` which I call from a `J2ME` client. When I run the app then the record is not inserted into the database ( I checked it through SQLYog ). It's the case of `insert` which causes problem , the `update` is ok.

So what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: The syntax of an insert is not TableName(Columns..) Set (values)  It is different from an update.  You should do Insert into TableName(columns...) values(Values...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert query syntax in the code is wrong. You should be using either of the following form.

```
INSERT into TABLE_NAME SET column_name1='value1',column_name2='value2'
```

or,

```
INSERT into TABLE_NAME (column_name1,column_name2) VALUES('value1','value2')
```

But in your code you have mixed up the insert syntax so it is not working. You can use `die(mysql_error())` to see the exact error generated by MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify column `(cr_date,cr_lieu,cred_id,cr_resultat,cr_comment,adc_id)` if using `INSERT` with  `SET`

Try Below:

```
 $requete = mysql_query("INSERT INTO compte_rendu SET
                          cr_date= '".convertFromDateHM($valeur[1])."',
                          cr_lieu = '".$valeur[2]."',
                          cred_id= '".$valeur[3]."',
                          cr_resultat = '".$valeur[5]."',
                          cr_comment = '".$valeur[6]."',
                          adc_id = '".$valeur[7]."' ");
```

OR You can use :

```
$requete = mysql_query("INSERT INTO compte_rendu(cr_date,cr_lieu,cred_id,cr_resultat,cr_comment,adc_id) VALUES (
                                        '".convertFromDateHM($valeur[1])."',
                                        '".$valeur[2]."',
                                        '".$valeur[3]."',
                                        '".$valeur[5]."',
                                        '".$valeur[6]."',
                                        '".$valeur[7]."' )");
```